# Masstransit Consumer in .NET 4.8 Topshelf works only in Executable not in Service

Tags: windows-services, masstransit, topshelf

we need to host a Masstransit RabbitMQ Consumer in a .NET 4.8 Windows Service.

We are using Dependency Injection and Topshelf to run, install and start the Service.

Running the Consumer as a Windows *.exe works fine: Messages are received.

But when starting as a Windows Service NO Messages are received as I can tell from the Log4Net Log.

This is the Main() Method using Topshelf to start our MassTransitRunner Instance with injected Logging and Configuration:

```
    var massTransitRunner = new MassTransitRunner(_logger, _config, args);
    _ = HostFactory.Run(x =>
    {
        x.Service<MassTransitRunner>(s =>
                            {
                                s.ConstructUsing(runner => massTransitRunner);
                                s.WhenStarted(runner => runner.Start());
                                s.WhenStopped(runner => runner.Stop());
                            });
        x.RunAsNetworkService();
        x.SetServiceName(nameof(RuleEngineCommandConsumer));
        x.SetDisplayName("_RuleEngine-CommandConsumer");
        x.SetDescription("Processes Commands with Results to trigger Transitions");
    });
```

And this is the Start()-Method of the MassTransitRunner class passed to Topshelf:

```
public void Start() {
    try
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Starting...");

        var hostBuilder = _args.CreateMassTransitHostBuilder(null, null, Program.ConfigureServices, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        _host = hostBuilder.UseWindowsService().Build();
        _task = _host.StartAsync(_Cancellation.Token);
        //_host.Start();
        //_host.RunAsync(_Cancellation.Token);
        //await _task; => stopped without Starting

        _logger.LogInformation("Started");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.LogError(e, "Starting...");
    }
}
```

As you can see we have experimented with different Methods to start the Host, but only StartAsync worked.

The full Example Project can be inspected [in Github](https://github.com/SpocWeb/RabbitMqConsumer.Cli)

Any Help is really appreciated!

Comment: 99.9% of the time, it's permissions related to the service account or how the service is setup to run on the server.

Comment: So the practice above is right? I also experimented with different users after registering the Service, especially myself (Computer Admin) but to no avail yet. Is there a Log Output that we can activate to better diagnose the Problem?

Comment: For example when changing the Namespace of the Message, all existing Messages were discarded due to the Mismatch. 

I would like to have Log Entries about such behavior but did not see any even when setting the Filter to 'ALL' in Log4Net

Comment: I looked at the repository, why aren't you just using the ConsoleHost? Topshelf seems extra, and all the hoops to get a host builder and service collection and still use the dead-end log4net is just a mess. I wouldn't want to support this code anywhere. I don't even support Topshelf anymore, and I wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was making it harder than necessary:

- TopShelf is not needed, because Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting NuGet Packages are built on .NET Standard 2.0 so they also work with .NET 4.8
- My main Mistake was to only Start() the Host, instead of Run()ing it. This allowed the Main() Method to terminate, taking the Host with it.

The working Main() Method now looks like this:

```
    var hostBuilder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);
    hostBuilder = hostBuilder.ConfigureMassTransitConsumers(null, null
        , Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    hostBuilder = hostBuilder.UseWindowsService(); //automatically detects whether in Service or Console...
    var host = hostBuilder.Build();
    host.Run(); //runs all registered IHostedService Classes and waits for their Completion
```

I have [updated the sample project with a working RabbitMq Consumer](https://github.com/SpocWeb/RabbitMqConsumer.Cli) hoping to give others a kick-start.

Thanks again to @chris-patterson for the quick answer and a great Messaging Framework!